# CRC32C checksum for HTTP Range Get requests in google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, http-headers, google-cloud-storage

When I want to get a partial range of file content in the google cloud storage, I used XML API and use HTTP Range Get requests. From the google cloud response, I can find the header `x-goog-hash`, and it contains CRC32C and MD5 checksums. But these checksums are calculated from the whole file. What I need is the crc32c checksum of the partial range of content in the response. With that partial crc32c checksum, I can verify the data in response, otherwise, I cannot check the validation of the response.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering: Are the files stored in your bucket on gzip format? I read here [Using Range Header on gzip-compressed files](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding#range) that you can't get partial information from a compressed file. By default you get the whole file information.

Anyways, could you share the petition you're sending?

Comment: Files are not stored with gzip. They are binary serialized data. My requests are in the following form:
`https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name/filename`
with headers: `Authorization: token`, `Range: bytes=0-999`

Answer (score 0):

I looked for more information and found this: [Request Headers and Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-object-download#request_headers).

It says that when you use the Range header, the returned checksum will cover the whole file.

So far, there's no way to get the checksum for a byte range alone using the XML API.

However, you could try to do it by splitting your file with your preferred programming language and get the checksum for that "splitted" part.

Comment: Thanks, my demand is to implement the function such as `fseek` and `fread`,  so I hope to access a part of a file randomly.